# Cannot instantiate implementation type for service type in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

My Excel service generates reports.

```
public class ExcelService : IExcelService
    {
        private readonly List<IReportFactory> _reports;

        public ExcelService(List<IReportFactory> reports)
        {
            _reports = reports;
        }

        public Stream Generate(string reportName, params ReportParameter[] parameters)
        {
            var reportFactory = GetReportFactory(reportName);
            var report = reportFactory.Create(parameters);

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(report.Generate());
            return stream;
        }

        private IReportFactory GetReportFactory(string reportName)
        {
            var reportFactory = _reports.Find(factory => factory.Name == reportName);
            if (reportFactory != null)
            {
                return reportFactory;
            }
            throw new NotSupportedException($"Report {reportName} is not supported. Report is not registerd.");
        }
    }

 //Service

public interface IExcelService
    {
        Stream Generate(string reportName, params ReportParameter[] parameters);
    }
```

To achieve that it uses ReportParameters from `IReportFactory`

```
public interface IReportFactory
    {
        string Name { get; }
        Report Create(ReportParameter[] parameters);
    }
```

which takes Name attribute from exact reports:

```
public class GIDReportFactory : IReportFactory
    {
        public const string Name = nameof(GIDReport);

        public const string DataSourceParam = "DataSource";
        string IReportFactory.Name
        {
            get
            {
                return Name;
            }
        }
    }
```

To make it work I had to add service in my `Startup.cs`

```
        private static void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IExcelService, ExcelService>();
        }
```

and now I'm stuck at error:

```
'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
'ServiceType: ...Services.IExcelService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: ...Services.ExcelService': Unable to resolve service for type 
 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1
[....Services.ExcelReports.Factories.IReportFactory]' while attempting to activate '...Services.ExcelService'.)'
```

I know that its connected with my `IRreportFactory` and fact that it's not included inside of `Startup.cs` file. But I've got no clue how I could possibly add it there.

While I tried adding it via `AddScoped<IReportFactory, GIDReportFactory>();` I'm ending up with error:

```
'Cannot instantiate implementation type '...Services.ExcelReports.Factories.IReportFactory' for service type '...Services.ExcelReports.Factories.IReportFactory'.'
```

I've got really no idea what might be the good solution.

Comment: Are you registering your `AddScoped<IReportFactory, GIDReportFactory>()` before your `IExcelService` (in startup class)?

Comment: If you ask me if line ```AddScoped<IReportFactory, GIDReportFactory>()``` is before ```services.AddScoped<IExcelService, ExcelService>();``` in ```private static void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)``` then yes. Otherwise I'm sorry but I've got no idea what you are talking about.
I've got really no clue how does all of this dependency injection works. I added service than uses ```IReportFactory``` and I have no idea how to add ```IReportFactory``` to ```Startup.cs``` so it would work

Comment: Can you show the complete code for ExcelService class? Especially its constructor. Based on your error message, I guess you have a constructor with a collection. Also, what does the method GetReportFactory(reportName) do?

Comment: The key to get Dependency Injection working is to have a correct class constructor. Without seeing your class, it's a bit difficult to suggest a fix. In your ExcelService class, I would expect public class ExcelService(IRreportFactory reportFactory).

Comment: Thank you for your time, I updated ExcelService class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ExcelService.cs, change the constructor as below,

```
public ExcelService(IEnumerable<IReportFactory> reports)
{
    _reports = reports.ToList();
}
```

Now, in your DI setup, add the below code,

```
services.AddScoped<IReportFactory, GIDReportFactory>();
services.AddScoped<IExcelService, ExcelService>();
```

See the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0#service-registration-methods).